# SQL Server: Determine backup location from physical_device_name field

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2016, backup

I am working on a SQL Server database and ran the following command to figure out where the database is backing up to:

```
SELECT TOP 1 M.physical_device_name
FROM msdb..backupset S
JOIN msdb..backupmediafamily M ON M.media_set_id=S.media_set_id
WHERE S.database_name = 'MyDB'
```

The physical_device_name says: **HTSQLServerMyDB**

I don't see any maintenance plans or jobs that I can figure out that do this backup. I am trying to figure out where it is doing this backup. If I go into **Server Objects** then **Backup Devices** it is empty.
How can I determine where are my backups?

I am running SQL Server 2016 (13.0.4001.0).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Does this [StackOverflow answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/55050753/5059085) point you in the right direction? Specifically if you look at the `device_type` column from the `backupmediafamily` table, what do you see? You can find the list of types in the [API doc](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/system-tables/backupmediafamily-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15):

> 2 = Disk
>
> 5 = Tape
>
> 7 = Virtual device
>
> 9 = Azure Storage
>
> 105 = A permanent backup device.

I'm almost wondering if that's a **CNAME** or some sort of name reference to the actual path, but it may be dependent on the above.

This is likely the relevant part from the above answer to what you're seeing:

> You should notice that these backups have value 7 in the column "device_type" (7 means Virtual device). These rows are actually very useful, for example it help to know that the Virtual Machine backups are running full database backups on a SQL Server instance.

> There's no trace of these backup files since they are above the scope of the virtual machine (above the level of your machine) - these are triggered by the host (Hyper-V or VMware for example).

Comment: So it is in fact 7 (Virtual Device). This server is hosted on a third party hosting service. I believe they use VMWare. Does this mean that it is part of their VM Backup?

Comment: @Rick I just updated my answer, but yes it sounds like your SQL Server instance's backups are being handled higher up outside the server, at the VM level.

Comment: So if a restore would be required, that would need to be handled by the host provider (I know I would need to check the contract)?

Comment: @Rick Yes, depending on your contract, that could be true. You'll need to reach out to your provider for the details. But regardless of what they're doing you still should be able to setup your own backups of the databases as well, if you wanted.

Comment: The problem is that the database is huge at about almost 2TB.

Comment: @Rick Not sure I follow? I've managed backups for databases with individual Tables that were each 2 TB big. The operation can be a little time consuming but usually that's the purpose of a maintenance window. If you need additional help with managing backups, feel free to open another question though and you'll likely get a lot of advice accordingly.